# Intellij IDEA lombok cannot find symbol symbol

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have already installed the lombok plugin,and enable the annotation processing .why still have the problem:"java:cannot find symbol"

Comment: you're going to need to provide some more details. It should say *which* symbol it can't find.  Are you using gradle? If so, post your script and dependencies

Comment: Hard to say.  The _very least_ you need to do is provide enough information for others to replicate the problem you have.  That said, lombok provides advanced functionality that primarily is for experienced users who know what they are doing.  I would suggest that you for now work without lombok so you understand what you doing and what you need to do, before coming back.

Comment: Can you show us the code with the problem?  Otherwise, all anyone can do is guess.